# Geolocation not working in React native project

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, geolocation, frontend

I create a project using expo:

```
expo init geotest
```

Next install lib:

```
npm install react-native-geolocation-service
```

Add permission in app.json:

```
"android": {
    "permissions": [
        "ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"
    ]
}
```

App.js contains the following code:

https://github.com/Agontuk/react-native-geolocation-service/blob/master/example/App.js

But when I call Geolocation.getCurrentPosition, I get a warning:

```
[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'RNFusedLocation.getCurrentPosition')]
```

All ideas are over, please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use the `expo-location` and read the documentation properly. here is link https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/location/ . if you are facing any issue by implementing this. then feel free to ask me. thank you.